# Date Format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with formatting a date that I receive from a MySQL database. I keep getting this error:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 23
```

Here is my code:

```
    $news_query = $database->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_NEWS . " ORDER BY 'date'");
    while($news_data = mysql_fetch_array($news_query,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $date = date("M d, Y - g:i:s A", $news_data['date']);
        echo "
        <DIV class = 'news_post'>
            <DIV class = 'news_title'>" . $news_data['title'] . "</DIV>
            <DIV class = 'news_info'>Posted on " . $date . " By " . $news_data["author"] . "</DIV>
            <DIV class = 'entry'>" . $news_data['entry'] . "</DIV>
        </DIV>";
    }
```

I have read over the PHP manual for timestamps and the date function and I can't seem to figure out what my problem is.

Comment: Which line is line 23? Odds are `$news_data['date']` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: What is the data type of `date` at mysql table ?

Comment: Line 23 is this: $date = date("M d, Y - g:i:s A", $news_data['date']); The type is a timestamp that uses CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: You don't need to add [solved] or anything else to the title. Marking an answer as a solution is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using datetime format in MySQL?

Try this:

```
<?php
    date("M d, Y - g:i:s A", strtotime( $news_data['date'] ) );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I have to wait 6 minutes to mark it as an answer though.

Answer (score 2):

The date from the database in `$news_data['date']` is probably a string representation of a date. The `date()` function takes a format string and an optional timestamp, which is an integer. This is the reason for the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will convert your date into the format required for `date()`.

Instead of:

```
$date = date("M d, Y - g:i:s A", $news_data['date'])
```

You want:

```
$date = date("M d, Y - g:i:s A", strtotime($news_data['date']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$database->query("SELECT *,unix_timestamp(date) as date 
                  FROM ".DB_NEWS." ORDER BY date")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.
The first is : use `UNIXTIMESTAMP` sql function in your query, or strtotime like said before.
The second, which I prefer is using DateTime PHP object.

```
$date = new DateTime($datas['date']);
//if an error occurs because of the format use createFromFormat
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y',$datas['date']);//for exemple for dd-mm-YYYY format
```